# repeat function every second

Tags: c#

I want to add to my local database every second, real time data, the only method is timer, but , i don't know where i can declare the class , and how i can use it

remark : `cn` is the SQL connection

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into supervision values("...........')", cn);
        /
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("insert into supervision values(" +.......')", cn);

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    cn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("database added");
}
```

Comment: Have you put your full efforts to write this question?

Comment: I suggest not to use term "realtime" if we talk about .NET applications. Realtime is a term with very specific meaning: everything happens exactly when it's expected to happen with given precision,  and if not - system will go to safe error state. PLCs are realtime, .NET is not realtime already by it's nature. I suggest to use "polling with interval".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Use [System.Timers.Timer](https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK4fXKiInNAhVCfywKHe4pACkQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.timers.timer(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHJqF5gXvc8-tHV7J0BggL6RowQnA)

2- Set [Interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx) to 1 Second

3- Handle the [Elapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) Event

4- Make you method thread safe by using [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), so that no 2 timers will insert to the database at the same time.

```
var mytimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
mytimer.Elapsed += Mytimer_Elapsed;
mytimer.Start();

private static object lockobject = new object();
private static void Mytimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(lockobject)
    {
        cn.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into supervision values("...........')", cn);
            /
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("insert into supervision values(" +.......')", cn);


                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("database added");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your code into a function.  Then call the function from within a timer with the intwrval set to 1000